# 100% floating div in height: auto parent

Tags: height, sticky-footer, css

I have a CSS-layout with a sticky footer. The main parts of the site are some sidebars and a content box. But I can't seem to get either the context box nor the surrounding div to expand to a height of "100%".

If the content box contains short text, it doesn't span over the full height and if it contains lots of text, the surrounding div doesn't.

The result should be a site where the content box AND the floating background expand to the bottom of the page just above the footer.

edit: adding "overflow: hidden" to #inner fixes the problem with the background not lining up with long content. But I still can't get the #content div to expand for the full page height.

http://jsfiddle.net/s6yf3/ (The Wikipedia logo is just for better visualization)

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner">   
    <header>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bc/Wiki.png" alt="Logo" width=400 height=100 />
      </a>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec libero vitae massa bibendum molestie ac non justo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent in dui arcu, nec ornare nibh.
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div>Element</div>
      <div>Element</div>
      <div>Element</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <p>Sticky Footer</p>
</div>
```

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background:#eee;
}

html,body {
  height:100%; 
}

#wrapper {
  width:400px;
  height: auto !important;
  height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  min-height:100%;
}

#inner {
  height: 100%;
  padding:0 0 55px 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-image: url(//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bc/Wiki.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: right bottom;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#inner p {
  margin:1em 1em 0;
  padding:.15em .25em;  
}

#inner header {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  height: 160px;
}

#wrapper header nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 4px;
  padding-left: 240px;
  height: 46px !important;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
}

#wrapper header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#wrapper header nav ul li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  height: 40px !important;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#wrapper header nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #333 !important;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}

#wrapper header nav ul li.active a {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #333 !important;
  color: #fff;
  height: 46px !important;
  line-height: 46px;
  display: block !important;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar div {
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 60px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#content {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#footer {
    width:400px;
    height:55px;
    margin:-55px auto 0;
    background:#222;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#footer p{
    margin:0;
    padding:.5em 0 0;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: post the relevant code in your question - not as a link

Answer (score 0):

Give `overflow:hidden;` to wrapper div, remove height and `margin-left: -55px` from footer, it should behave as expected.

UPDATED FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/Tnc4t/4/

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to fix it. The content div and the div in the background are both not expanding to full height. The only visible change is a "bug" to the footer and the scrollbar is visible all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Because #inner and #wrapper have heights of 100%, I placed #footer inside #inner and removed the 65px bottom padding from #inner.

jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rPGTq/

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner">   
    <header>
      ...
    </header>
    <div id="content">
      ...
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      ...
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <p>Sticky Footer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That solves the problem with the background not expanding in size. This is how I wanted the background to behave. But now the footer isn't "sticky" anymore and doesn't stay on the bottom of the page. Additional the footer can overlap the sidebar if the content div gets to small.

Comment: Hi @armin. When I clicked the link to your jFiddle, the footer wasn't sticky, which also made me a little confused. Would you mind checking the jFiddle again and give me another link? I think the code may have changed since you last posted it. The link defau1t posted is exactly the same as yours. From there, I'll investigate again and revise my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I checked the link (http://jsfiddle.net/Tnc4t/) and it appears sticky in my browser (Chrome). Thanks for your effort so far.

Comment: Hi @tnsingle, I got the #inner line up with #content. At least with long content. With fewer text #content still doesn't expand. http://jsfiddle.net/s6yf3/

Comment: Thanks @armin. I've been trying to find a solution, but I keep hitting dead ends :-/